# Disable call back link on text message previews?

Tags: sms, samsung, notifications, 5.1-lollipop

Android 5.1.1 on a Samsung Note 4.  Text message notifications show the text message and then "CALL" and "REPLY" links.  Sometimes I accidentally hit the "CALL" button and find myself calling someone I did not want to call at that time.

How can I disable/remove the "CALL" link? (or if there is an alternative way to avoid the accidental calling)

Comment: You might not be able to remove that link – but you could use a [Call Confirm](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_96) app.

Comment: In case you ever get some spare time, you can experiment with Tasker and AutoNotification app. Disable notifications for your default SMS app, have Tasker listen to incoming messages and pass the info to AutoNotification to create a notification for the received SMS, with added flexibility of showing buttons of your interest.